# How do i bind to a NSString?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

This question was asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382430/how-to-bind-nsstring-value-in-cocoa), but its not answered.

I can bind to objects like so:

```
[[aCellView textField] bind:@"stringValue"
                               toObject:myObject
                            withKeyPath:@"text"
                                options:nil]];
```

This works easy because i have a `myObject.text` value.
But how do i bind to NSString?

```
[[aCellView textField] bind:@"stringValue"
                               toObject:aString
                            withKeyPath:@""  // What should the keyPath be?
                                options:nil]];
```

Comment: Cocoa-touch doesn't support cocoa bindings. The closest you will get is KVO. See here for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812972/is-there-any-data-binding-mechanism-available-for-ios

Comment: Or just use associated objects.

Comment: I accidentally added Cocoa touch. I have now removed the Cocoa-touch tag.  
@H2CO3 you say the keypath should be @"associatedObjects" ?

Comment: @H2CO3 How would you emulate bindings with associated objects? I don't really see what these have to do with each other.

Comment: @Jai No. I meant the `objc_[set|get]AssociatedObject()` API.

Comment: @omz If I'm not mistaken, OP wants to associate objects with other object quite arbitrarily, but he couldn't find a way for doing so without specifying explicit properties. The question is quite vague TBH, and I apologize if that's not what he wants.

Comment: ...Just like someone can bind a cell's stringValue on a NSTableCellView to show the content of myObject.text, i just want to know how (or if its even possible) to bind the cell's stringValue to a NSString.

Comment: `NSString` is immutable, it doesn't really make sense to bind to an object that never changes... @H2CO3 Read about bindings on OS X, it's a well-defined mechanism that has more to do with KVO than with associated objects (and doesn't exist on iOS).

Comment: @omz Didn't relalize "binding" is the name of a Cocoa technology... Thanks! (And heck, yeah, observing an object which doesn't mutate is quite boring, indeed.)

Comment: The best part about this question is that `stringValue` has never been a valid binding.

Comment: @omz but the NSString value does change. But not by user. It changes with code and constantly updates. So i just wanted the TableViewCell to reflect that.

Comment: No, the string itself doesn't *change*, it's *replaced* by a different object that knows nothing about the previous value.

Comment: @omz ok last question.. what if the string was NSMutableString ?

Comment: @Jai Then it would suddenly make sense to observe it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* bind to individual objects, but not temporaries.  One of the reasons why we bind to key paths is to have a little more sense about the lifetime of the variable, and therefore, the binding.  Make `aString` a property of the calling object, and bind to `self` with `aString` as the key path:

```
[[aCellView textField] bind:NSValueBinding toObject:self withKeyPath:@"aString" options:@{}];
```