# Is there a MonoTouch.Dialog port to Silverlight/wp7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am thinking about [how an application can be written to work on both Windows 7 Phone and IPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812125/how-do-i-create-an-application-that-works-on-both-the-windows-7-phone-and-iphone), one option is [MonoTouch.Dialog](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/Feb-23.html) for most of the UI on the IPhone and then create a layer that will let the some code work on WP7.

Has anyone looked at doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen a port to WP7 of MonoTouch.Dialog yet. But it could definitely be done.

MonoTouch Dialog is really two different things that work together: the first creates the structure of the data (either from reflection or creating elements manually) and the second actually displays that structure in a table.

Both parts are kind of mixed in the same code today, so separating those two would be the first step, so that the first part doesn't depend on MonoTouch.* at all. The second step would be to port the second part of the code to WP7.

That would be a really cool project, actually. It would be very useful.

Comment: MonoTouch.Dialog looks so match easier then Silverlight for simple “config” pages, that I can see uses for it on WP7 even if I did not wish to target the ITouch.

Comment: Yup, I agree.. we really need help porting the project to other platforms.

Answer (score 1):

There was an post about this recently on [Monologue](http://go-mono.com/monologue/):

http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2010/09/monotouch-meet-windowsphone7.html

Comment: Thanks, however this does not cover MontoTouch.Dialog it's self.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea with regards to creating the custom UI's for each OS which access the same data.

However, Monotouch.Dialog is specific to iPhone (as the name, Monotouch suggests). There may be a similar port to WM7 which allows for easy creation of WM7 UI elements but I doubt it would be a fork from Monotouch.Dialog because it is specific to iPhone.

Comment: As the look of the UI has to be about the same due to small sceen size and Montotouch.Dialog come before WP7,  a fork of Montotouch.Dialog does make sence.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting using a fork from Monotouch.Dialog didn't make sense, merely that I doubt there will be a port of Monotouch.Dialog to the WM7. There may be a similar, WM7 specific, library which allows easy creation of WM7 UIs though